# Finding common ranking of contestants in dance competition

Tags: combinatorics

At a dance competition there are a number of contestants and $64$ judges. Each judge ranks the contestants from best to worst, with no ties. For any three contestants $A,B,C$, there do not exist three judges such that one ranks $A$ above $B$ above $C$, another ranks $B$ above $C$ above $A$, and the third ranks $C$ above $A$ above $B$. Prove that we can rank the contestants so that for any two contestants $A,B$, the one who is ranked higher in our ranking is ranked higher by at least half of the judges.

If there are two judges, we can create a graph of contestants, and put the edge $A\rightarrow B$ if both judges rank $A$ above $B$. This graph will have no cycle, which means we can return any [topological ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) of the graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each pair $\{A,B\}$ of distinct contestants rank $A$ above $B$ if a majority of the judges rank $A$ above $B$; this yields a partial final ranking. To show that it’s consistent, suppose not: then there are three contestants $A,B$, and $C$ such that a majority of judges rank $A$ above $B$, a majority of judges rank $B$ above $C$, and a majority of judges rank $C$ above $A$. But any two majorities have a judge in common, so there are a judge who ranks $A$ above $B$ above $C$, a judge who ranks $B$ above $C$ above $A$, and a judge who ranks $C$ above $A$ above $B$, contradicting the hypothesis.

Let $\mathscr{C}$ be the set of contestants, and for $A,B\in\mathscr{C}$ write $A\ge B$ if either $A=B$, or a majority of judges rank $A$ above $B$. We’ve just seen that $\ge$ is a on $\mathscr{C}$. Let $\succeq$ be any linear (total) order extending $\ge\,$; it’s straightforward to verify that a final ranking that ranks $A$ above if and only if $A\succ B$ has the desired property.